# jQuery glitch? toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm learning javascript and jQuery and have come across a wierd glitch unless I'm doing something wrong?

Or maybe its jsfiddle?

Could you take a look at the code below and let me know if it's me? When you uncomment out the section of code I have commented, toggleClass stops working.

https://jsfiddle.net/0y4neucq/5/

```
$('tr.discrepancy').click(function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    /*var clicked = event.target.nodeName;
  if (clicked != "INPUT") {
    $("input[type='checkbox']", this).trigger("click");
  }*/

  $('p').html(clicked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because when you `.trigger("click")` on the checkbox it fires the `$('tr.discrepancy').click()` handler again, this is because events bubble up the chain. You can see this in the console on this fiddle where I added a console.log: https://jsfiddle.net/0y4neucq/11/

You can either prevent the click on the checkbox propagating up by adding a click handler and calling `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (event) { event.stopPropagation() });
```

Or you can check/uncheck the checkbox without triggering a click like so:

```
var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']")
checkbox.attr("checked", !checkbox.attr("checked"));
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm guessing it would loop then if I didn't have the 'if'.